# Отправка СМС на кирилице

Tags: delphi, at, 3g

Delphi 10.3 + BComPort.

3g Hyawei E153 на AT+CSCS=? отвечает -

```
+CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2")
OK
```

Приведенный ниже код без проблем отправляет сообщение на латинице (закоментированная строка). С русскими буквами - ошибка (+CMS ERROR: 305).

Если раскоментировать закоментированные строки - модем отключается на несколько секунд и находится опять. Пробовал Sleep(7000) - не помогло. 7 секунд подобрал экспериментально.

```
    function EncodeUnicodeToUCS2(const S: string): string;
    var
      I: Integer;
    begin
      Result := '';
      for I := 1 to Length(S) do
      begin
        Result := Result + IntToHex(Ord(S[I]), 4);
      end;
    end;
    
    
    procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      AStr: AnsiString;
      StringNumber: String;
      StringMessage: String;
    begin
      StringNumber := '+XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //- номер в правильном формате
      StringMessage := 'Тестовое сообщение 123 TEST test ';
//      StringMessage := '123 TEST test ';
    
      AStr := 'AT+CMGF=1' + #13#10;
      frmMain.BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
      Sleep(100);
    
      AStr := 'AT+CSCS="UCS2"' + #13#10; // Устанавливаем кодировку UCS2
      frmMain.BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
      Sleep(100);
    
    //  AStr := 'AT+CSMP=17,167,0,8' + #13#10; // Устанавливаем кодировку UCS2
    //  frmMain.BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
    //  Sleep(500);
    
      AStr := 'AT+CMGS="' +EncodeUnicodeToUCS2(StringNumber) + '"' + #13;
      frmMain.BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
      Sleep(100);
    
      AStr := EncodeUnicodeToUCS2(StringMessage) + #26;
      frmMain.BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
      Sleep(500);
    end;
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [отправка СМС с русскими символами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%a1%d0%9c%d0%a1-%d1%81-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)